# Split the line into 2 in DT table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

from the below dataset, can we split the line in Cola into 2 lines as shown in expected output? The same line but splitted into 2 lines?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
 
ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("example_table")
)
 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  new_data <- data.frame(cola = c("fsdfdsgfsdgfdgfdgfdgdhgdgdfgdfgsfsgsfgsfdgfdgdfgfdgsfgfgfdgdd","fsgfdgfdgdfsdfgdfgdhdfgsdfsdfgfgdhdhfghfghfghsdfs"), b=c(1,2))
 
  output$example_table <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(new_data,escape = FALSE)
  })
}
 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Expected output

[image]

Comment: do you want to randomly break the line or what? can you be more precise?

Comment: No no. Not a random one. Below answers my question 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply insert `<br>` at the point you want the line break.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("example_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  new_data <- data.frame(cola = c("fsdfdsgfsdgfdgfdgfdgdhgdgd<br>fgdfgsfsgsfgsfdgfdgdfgfdgsfgfgfdgdd","fsgfdgfdgdfsdfgdfgdhdfgsdf<br>sdfgfgdhdhfghfghfghsdfs"), b=c(1,2))
  
  output$example_table <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(new_data,escape = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Hi. This solves my question. Just want to check , can we not make without putting line break in between . I mean can we make it more dynamic? If the width of the column exceed so, a automatically it should go to next line?

Comment: As far as I know, If there is not enough horizontal space datatable automatically breaks the line. To insert `<br>` programatically use `paste0` or `sprintf`.

Comment: Sorry didn’t get like. You mean paste those values ?